# Change color of a text according to displayed word

Tags: javascript

I have a delivery panel page and I want the color of a displayed text change according to the text showed by our system, I can't use CSS because the displayed text change according to the delivery payment method.

For example, if the text is "Cash" it will be blue and is the text is "Card" it will be red, I made a really fast code but i'm lost on the error

Hope you can help on this, thanks

```js
switch (text) {
  case "Cash":
    {
      document.getElementById("test").style.color = "blue";
      break;
    }
  case "Card":
    {
      document.getElementById("test").style.color = "red";
      break;
    }
}
```

```css
.test {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}

#text {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<a class="test" id="text">Cash Card</a>
<a class="test">Card Cash</a>
```

Comment: The `text` in the switch statement doesn't represent anything. It isn't a variable, or a parameter to a function.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot change individual words in a block of text, but in my answer below I added a possible solution which involves wrapping the words you want to colour in a `span`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot replace individual words in a text with a different style, but what you could do is to wrap said words in a `span` and that span can then have the style. I've created a snipped below as an example:

```js
let text = document.getElementById("text");
let text2 = document.getElementById("text2");
addColor(text);
addColor(text2);

function addColor(text) {
  text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.replace(
    /(cash)/gi,
    '<span style="color: blue">$1</span>'
  );
  text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.replace(
    /(card)/gi,
    '<span style="color: red">$1</span>'
  );
}
```

```css
.test {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}

#text {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<a class="test" id="text">Cash Card</a>
<a class="test" id="text2">Card Cash</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue is that your `switch` statement needs to find the right element and use its `innerHTML`.

The other issues you had were a few typos. The working code is below.

```html
<a class="test" id="text">Cash</a>
<a class="test">Card</a>

<style>

.test {
  font-size:14px;
  color: #333;
}

#text {
  font-size:18px;
  color: #333;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

var text = document.getElementById("text");

switch(text.innerHTML){
    case "Cash":{
        text.style.color = "blue";
        break;
    }
    case "Card":{
        text.style.color = "red";
        break;
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that:

```html
<a class="test">Cash</a>
<a class="test">Card</a>

<style>

.test {
  font-size:14px;
  color: #333;
}

#text {
  font-size:18px;
  color: #333;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var list= document.getElementsByClassName('test');
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var item = list[i];
      switch(item.textContent){
          case "Cash":{
              item.style.color = "blue";
              break;
          }
          case "Card":{
              item.style.color = "red";
              break;
          }
      }
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  switch(elements[i].innerText) {
  case "Cash":
    elements[i].style.color = "blue";
    break;
  case "Card":
    elements[i].style.color = "red";
    break;
  default:
    elements[i].style.color = "#333";
   }
  }
```

```css
.test {
  font-size:14px;
  color: #333;
}

#text {
  font-size:18px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="checks">
  
  <a class="test" id="text">Cash</a>
  <a class="test">Card</a>
</div>
```